# ActionFunction is not calling oncomplete method

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

I have jQuery Datatable which should be re-rendered after performing some tasks. I have used actionfunction to achieve this. The action function is calling apex method as well however the problem is when I add `reRender` or `oncomplete` then it is not working.

> Error is: Uncaught TypeError: actionUrl.indexOf is not a function

Any idea/suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<apex:actionFunction name="callApexMethod" action="{!callingApexMethod}" oncomplete="callMe();return false;" />
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isApprovedOther}" selected="true" onclick="setChkBoxValueOtherJS();return false;">
    </apex:inputcheckbox>
<script>

    function setChkBoxValueOtherJS() {
    alert('Inside Js');
    callApexMethod();
    }

    function callMe() {
    alert('Inside callMe');
    }
</script>

// Controller public class abc(){ public pageReference callingApexMethod(){ // some code return null; } }
```

Comment: We need to see your code to be able to help you

Comment: If you can provide us with some code it will be helpful for us to help you precisely and more accurately...

Comment: <apex:actionFunction name="callApexMethod" action="{!callingApexMethod}" oncomplete="callMe();return false;"/>
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isApprovedOther}" selected="true" onclick="setChkBoxValueOtherJS();return false;">
                                                 </apex:inputcheckbox>    
      
  <script>
   function setChkBoxValueOtherJS(){
 alert('Inside Js');
 callApexMethod();    
 }
 function callMe(){
 alert('Inside callMe');
 }
  
  </script>

Comment: // Controller
  
  public class abc(){
  public pageReference callingApexMethod(){
    // some code
    return null;
    }
  
  }

Comment: You might try changing your apex method from a return type of PageReference to a public void.

Comment: I have tried that as well but still it doesn't works.